# Understanding of CUDA's cudaGetSymbolAddress

Tags: memory, memory-management, cuda

I am new to CUDA, now I'm trying to understand how `cudaGetSymbolAddress` works. I get an unexpected Segmentation Fault in a really simple code. What I do is the following:

1. I declare a global device variable(`device_int`)
2. In main() I ensure that the definition was correct by setting its value in a kernel
3. I create a pointer (`host_pointer_to_device_int`) in host memory and make it point to `device_int` via `cudaGetSymbolAddress`
4. I create one more pointer (`host_pointer_to_host_int`) and try to `cudaMemcpy` the value from host_pointer_to_device_int to host_pointer_to_host_int

All these operations finish with no errors, but I get Segmentation Fault when trying to print the `host_pointer_to_host_int`'s value. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;


__device__ int device_int;


__global__ void kernel()
{
    device_int = 1000;
}


int main()
{
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    assert(cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess); // The above operation executed successfully

    int *host_pointer_to_device_int;
    cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&host_pointer_to_device_int, device_int);
    assert(cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess); // The above operation executed successfully

    int *host_pointer_to_host_int;
    // Copy the device_int's value
    cudaMemcpy((void **)&host_pointer_to_host_int, host_pointer_to_device_int,
            sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    assert(cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess); // The above operation executed successfully

    cout << *host_pointer_to_host_int << endl; // Segmentation fault
}
```

Comment: host_pointer_to_host_int makes no sense. You are trying to treat the value int(1000) as a pointer, which is obviously wrong. host_pointer_to_host_int should just be an int, not a pointer. There is nothing wrong with your the use of the device symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake was not in misunderstanding how cudaGetSymbolAddress works, but in using cudaMemcpy with wrong parameters types: I expected cudaMemcpy to allocate memory for me, so I've cast my variables to the wrong types.

The corrected code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;


__device__ int device_int;


__global__ void kernel()
{
    device_int = 1000;
}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    assert(cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess);

    int *host_pointer_to_device_int;
    /* Get a pointer to device_int. After this, I won't be able to access it,
     * but I'm going to copy its value with cudaMemcpy */
    cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&host_pointer_to_device_int, device_int);
    assert(cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess); // The above operation executed successfully

    int host_int;
    // Copy the device_int's value
    cudaMemcpy(&host_int, host_pointer_to_device_int,
            sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    assert(cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess); // The above operation executed successfully

    cout << host_int << endl; // Everything's fine!
}
```

Thanks to @talonmies for helping me in figuring it out.